# How to use mongoose findById() and populate() in javascript?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

Im trying to create a list of items for each users, which means user can create items and ı want to keep that data for each user.
Which I create two different schemas for that in:

> user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

userSchema = new Schema({
  unique_id: Number,
  email: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  passwordConf: String,
  teamname: String,

  items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }],
});

(ItemSchema = new Schema({
  createrId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

  productname: String,
  description: String,
  price: String,
  totalStock: String,
})),
  (Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema));
User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = { Item, User };
```

After creating 2 schemas ı used them in index.js that routers everything together.

> index.js

```
router.get('/create_item', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.render('items.ejs');
});

router.post(
  '/create_item',
  function (
    req,
    res,
    next // Try to create items in database
  ) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var itemInfo = req.body;

    if (
      !itemInfo.itemname ||
      !itemInfo.itemdsc ||
      !itemInfo.itemstock ||
      !itemInfo.itemprice
    ) {
      res.send();
    } else {
      var NewItem = new Item({
        createrId: loggedInUser._id,
        productname: itemInfo.itemname,
        description: itemInfo.itemdsc,
        price: itemInfo.itemprice,
        totalStock: itemInfo.itemstock,
      });

      NewItem.save(function (err, Item) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log('Item added succesfully !');
      });
    }

    User.findById(loggedInUser._id)
      .populate('items')
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Suceess ? : ', result.items);
          console.log(loggedInUser._id);
        }
      });
  }
);
```

I keep the data for loggedInUser in **'/login'** so it is return me a value.
My output is

```
    "Suceess ? :[]
6379921faf39150008fa1b88
Item added succesfully !
```

Which ı think the problem is from the output it trying to populate item after Item is created but how can ı solve this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code is not executing sequentially (`NewItem.save` logs after `User.findById`).
Try to use `async await`, also you will need to add the newly created item `_id` to the corresponding `User` to add the new reference to the `items` array:

```
router.post(
  '/create_item',
  async function (
    req,
    res,
    next // Try to create items in database
  ) {
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
      var itemInfo = req.body;

      if (
        !itemInfo.itemname ||
        !itemInfo.itemdsc ||
        !itemInfo.itemstock ||
        !itemInfo.itemprice
      ) {
        return res.send('Incomplete parameters');
      }

      const newItem = await Item.create({
        createrId: loggedInUser._id,
        productname: itemInfo.itemname,
        description: itemInfo.itemdsc,
        price: itemInfo.itemprice,
        totalStock: itemInfo.itemstock,
      });

      const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(loggedInUser._id, {
        $push: { items: newItem._id },
      }, { new: true })
        .populate('items')
        .exec();

      console.log('Suceess ? : ', result.items);
      console.log(loggedInUser._id);
      return res.send('Finished');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, it this code it just push the item.id that correspond to user, however ı would like to take all the product informations to array of items in User, isn it populate by itself done it ? At the end ı want to show in the  front end, all the items that each user created.

Comment: by the way, when ı check the items in MongoDB it just shows me a ObjectId's of it, ı could not understant whether it is working or not.

Comment: @Razbolt When you store a `ref` to another field only the `ObjectId` is saved. This value is then populated with the referenced document attributes at query time (if you populate it). You need to add the references of the `Item`s manually to the respective `User`s on creation, the `items` list won't populate automatically.

Comment: hey,ı dont think ı understant this, if it is convenient for you, could you show me that how can ı do this ?, should ı push all the items attributes in '$push :{  }'